# The call is ambiguous: Html.LabelFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I just upgraded my MVC3 application to MVC4 and am getting an error at runtime. (Trimmed down to look better)

> error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
>       '`MyWebCore.HtmlHelperExtensions.LabelFor<CoreViewModel,string>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<CoreViewModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<CoreViewModel,string>>, object)`' and
>       '`System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor<CoreViewModel,string>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<CoreViewModel>, 
>       System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<CoreViewModel,string>>, object)`'

I have my own `LabelHelperExtensions` class that contains a `LabelFor` method. Both of my Web.config files have references to MVC4 in them. How can I use my extension methods instead of the MVC ones?

My web.config: `add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35`

My Views/web.config: `add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc"`

Comment: Did you check the version you are setting to MVc in web.config? Problably your mvc application is referencing two versions of MVC assembly.

Comment: @FelipeOriani No, both of my web.config files are referencing MVC 4.0

Comment: Hi! I'm getting the same error as you were. Did you find a solution to this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I have my own LabelHelperExtensions class that contains a LabelFor method.  How can I use my extension methods instead of the MVC ones?

Not the only option, but renaming your method to avoid the collision with the known extension method would be cleanest.  You could also call the static method directly (prefacing the method with the static class name) but that would defeat the purpose of using an extension method.

Comment: Thanks for the help, not my exact solution but led my to figure it out.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. MVC3 didn't have that ability, so many people wrote their own extensions class to have the LabelFor functionality. Upgrading to MVC4 now causes a clash as it now has that LabelFor method, so the solution is to remove your own extension (or rename it to have a different name/signature).

Answer (score 1):

First, why are you trying to override MVC's LabelFor extension when there is already another method to do this?

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

You may have a legitimate reason to be doing what you're doing, I don't know, but I'd look into the supported way to extend these helpers.

Comment: Thanks for the help, not my exact solution but led my to figure it out. I removed one of my overridden methods and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a number of cascading overridden methods that mirrors the structure of the MVC version of the `LabelExtensions` class. I was not able to remove them all, but I figured out which one was causing problems and removed it.